# What is the name of this URL part?

Tags: asp.net, http, url

If I have a URL:

```
http://mysite.com/part1/page.aspx
```

What is the name of the `part1` part in that URL?

Comment: If you have a URL: `http://mysite.com/part1/part2/page.aspx`
Then which of these components are you looking for a name for? `/part1/part2` or `part2`?

Comment: @AndreD: Good point. I need to name `/part1/part2` part.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about very basic thing of asp.net

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Justin is correct - it's one part of the path. Adding a reference to the [URI RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986), for the pretty picture contained therein, which illustrates ([in section 3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3)) each part of an example URI:

```
  foo://example.com:8042/over/there?name=ferret#nose
  \_/   \______________/\_________/ \_________/ \__/
   |           |            |            |        |
scheme     authority       path        query   fragment
```

Further on, in [the section devoted to the path](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.3):

> A path consists of a sequence of **path segments** separated by a slash
> ("/") character.  A path is always defined for a URI, though the
> defined path may be empty (zero length).  Use of the slash character
> to indicate hierarchy is only required when a URI will be used as the
> context for relative references.  For example, the URI
> mailto:fred@example.com has a path of "fred@example.com", whereas
> the URI foo://info.example.com?fred has an empty path. (emphasis mine)

And so "path segment" might be the term you're looking for.

Comment: "path segment" might be what the OP is looking for, but if he needs a term that refers to the entire path omitting the final component, or all path segments preceding the final slash, then he might want something like "parent path". Or, borrowing from common file-system terminology, "directory name" or "directory path" might work.

Answer (score 1):

That would be the first part of the path. There's no term to describe that part alone.

Comment: Haha. That's what I was thinking. It is not a `subfolder`, is it?

Comment: Nope. It may be a subfolder in a filesystem but it may also be something else depending on how the request is routed.

Comment: I just need to name it something in my form that I'm developing.

Answer (score -1):

I might possibly be name "the protocol"?

Comment: `http` is the protocol.

Comment: sorry just realized what you were looking for