# If I have a URL String but one part is dynamic should I break it in two or can I insert a variable in the middle?

Tags: java, url

I'm trying to build a URL that I'll use in a POST request. The completed URL will look something like this:

```
http://somesite.com/post/member/{AccountNumber}/verify/etc
```

The AccountNumber will be dynamic.

That can be done easily enough by having something like this:

```
String PATH1 = "http://somesite.com/post/member/"
String PATH2 = "/verify/etc"
String accountNumber;     //set account Number somewhere in the code

public String buildURL(String path1, String path2, String accoundNumber) {
    String url = path1 + accountNumber + path2
    return url;
}
```

I was wondering if I could do this more cleanly by having just one PATH. I'd like to read in the path from a yml or properties file and then dynamically insert the AccountNumber. Is it possible to do this?

So, my buildURL would look something like this:

```
String PATH = http://somesite.com/post/member/{AccountNumber}/verify/etc
String accountNumber;     //set account Number somewhere in the code

public String buildURL(String path, String accoundNumber) {
    String url = path{insert AccountNumber somehow}
    return url;
}
```

Or should I just stick with breaking it in two (I am overthinking this?)? Thanks.

EDIT: I realize I may have misused some terms. Not 100$ sure if it should be called 'PATH1', 'PATH2' etc since after looking here: [What is the name of this URL part?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19850031/what-is-the-name-of-this-url-part)
it seems like I'm including the 'scheme' and 'authority' part of the URL as PATH1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two different mechanisms in Java to accomplish this:

## java.text.MessageFormat

```
    String url = MessageFormat.format("http://somesite.com/post/member/{0}/verify/etc","1234567");
    System.out.println(url);
```

## java.util.Formatter:

```
    Formatter  f = new Formatter(new StringBuilder());
    f.format("http://somesite.com/post/member/%s/verify/etc", "1234546");
    System.out.println(f.toString());
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! This was exactly what I was looking for.